# Calculate sums for all given m.

Tags: summation, combinations

Let:
$S_m = \sum_{k=0}^n{((-1)^{n-k}}C_n^kk^m)$.

I need to calculate $S_m$ for all $m=0, 1, \ldots, n-1$.

As I undertood, it should be equal to zero for all $n, m$ (according to some computations on my PC). But I have no idea how to solve it more formally.

Comment: @BernardPan This is nonsense, you cannot put the $k^m$ out of the sum !!

Comment: @TheSilverDoe You are right. I did not notice this.

Comment: @Someone Do you know how to deal with the case $m=1$ ?